# Html.Action throws "asynchronous operation" InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm really stuck on this.

My actionresult is as follows

```
public ActionResult HolidayReport()
{
    return View("~/Views/Employee/GetEmployeeHolidayReport.cshtml");
}
```

Which currently has the view content of

```
<div class="panel panel-default panel-main">
    <div class="panel-body">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("Test"); }        
    </div>
</div>
```

For completion sake, this is the `Test` action

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Without even going to the controller or anything of the sorts it throws me the exception

```
An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.
```

on the `@{ Html.RenderAction("Test"); }` part in the view.
Exchanging it for @Html.Action() results in the same problem. What might be going on?

Comment: Post your `Test` action.

Comment: It is not even getting into the controller, I've tried different actions already. Both async Task<ActionResult> and regular ActionResult

Answer (score 2):

The `Test` action is presumably asynchronous (returning a `Task<T>`). [Asynchronous child actions are not supported on ASP.NET MVC 4](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/601). Note that asynchronous view components *are* supported on ASP.NET Core.

If you're not ready to migrate to ASP.NET Core yet, then your best option is to make `Test` synchronous.

Comment: Test was just a method I ended up creating in frustration, it is a normal ActionResult. But it is not even getting into the controller, it throws an exception in the view and tosses the exception into the errorhandler

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it ended up being caused by a controller I inherited from. The parent controller had its initialize method overridden and marked async.